# Can anyone tell me what :x: is used for?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

could anyone tell me what :x: is used for? I've searched the web with not many results.  An example would be the following:

```
`grep $USER:x: /etc/passwd'
```

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: To paraphrase fedorqui's answer: it's only part of the pattern you give to grep to search in the file.

Comment: For other references on similar topics consider asking on http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I'm not saying it's wrong to ask here, but you can get special domain knowledge there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$USER:x:` is the pattern you give to `grep` to search in `/etc/passwd`. It will return those lines containing `$USER:x:`, where `$USER` is the user with which you are currently working in the shell. Hence, the command will return the line in `/etc/passwd` in which your user is defined.

If you check how the `/etc/passwd` file is stored then you see that the 2nd block is normally `x`, meaning that the password is encrypted and stored in the `/etc/shadow` file. In old machines the password could be stored in `/etc/passwd`, but it was changed because this file is readable to any user, while `/etc/shadow` just to root.

That said, using `$USER:x` you assure you are just matching exactly this user. In fact, `^$USER:` would suffice, because `:` cannot be present in a user name.

An alternative is to use `awk` for example:

```
awk -F: -v user=$USER '$1==user' /etc/passwd
```

See the graphical explanation of `/etc/passwd` (sorry it is a bit big!! couldn't find any other smaller in English):

> [image]

Comment: +1, but the "x" indicates that the password is encrypted and in the shadow file. In very early, old, insecure iterations the password would have been in this file. (I don't think your answer makes this clear... yet.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer once stackoverflow lets me which should be in a few minutes

Comment: @kojiro many thanks! Yes, I was about to indicate so. I have seen some Solaris with the info in /etc/passwd, ufff :)